# Saving single pages of a word file as separate documents using COM

Tags: php, com, ms-word

Lately I've been playing with Microsoft COM object class for PHP to manipolate word files. So far so good, as I've been able to make it work and do some file conversions, such as saving an entire DOC as a PDF on the server.

Now I'm facing a problem: since I'll be converting and manipulating the given word file a lot at runtime, I thought it would be much better if I could save every single -page- separately and work on them one by one instead of reprocessing the whole document each time.

I have been reading all the [MSDN part about the COM Document Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1te11axx%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), and I have the feeling that I can't save just one page of the document, unless I do some sort of magic using the [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.range%28VS.80%29.aspx) Method, but apparently there's -no way- to know the 'current end position' for each page. Any ideas?

**tl;dr** I'm trying to save single pages inside a word document using a 'word.application' COM object through a PHP script, but I can't find examples of the Document.Range method.

Comment: Do not use Word Automation on a server.

Answer (score 1):

Francesco, I'll have to warn you. @SLaks is correct in that you really cannot use Word Automation on a server. No, really. We're serious.

There are two reasons:

First, Word is an incredibly complex piece of software designed to be used by an interactive user. It was not programmed or tested to be used under a server environment, and **does not** work correctly when running under a non-interactive account (the way services do). Sooner or later it will crash or freeze. I've seen it. I'm not talking necessarily about bugs. There are things that Word will do that require a full user account; or where Word expects somebody will be clicking on message boxes. There is no escaping it.

Second, because even if you manage to make it do what you want, it turns out that the Office license expressely forbids you from running Word that way.

Now, exclusively from the point of view of Automation:

Word doesn't really manipulate 'pages'. 'Pages' are just an incidental side-effect of whichever printer is currently selected. Take the same file to a different computer with a different printer and/or driver, and the pagination can change. On large documents it *will* change.

Yes, most of the time the page breaks don't move (a lot), particularly if you have a document that is a bunch of not-quite-a-full-page forms, but I'm not trying to be fastidious: The point is, the Word document object model won't help you a lot to manipulate 'pages' because they are not a first-class citizen but incidental formatting.

I guess that your best bet would be to use section breaks between the pages, instead of letting the pages autoflow; that way you have something for the object model to grab onto.

You can use the `ActiveDocument.Sections` collection to locate your... *ahem*... 'pages' (really, `section` objects), then use the `Range` method (to extract the `Range` object) and the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method to export that range to a PDF.

If you want a Word document instead, I don't think the object model allows you to save a piece of the document as a separate document. However you can easily copy-and-paste the range to a new document and save that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have written some code in VB.net that splits a passed word document into individual pages. It then goes on to save the pages as JPG images so I would think this is what you want.
I am happy to share the code with you if you've not accomplished the task yet?